# Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneOS8.4.sdk'

Tags: swift, xcode7

Yesterday I downloaded release version of Xcode 7.0 and while I build my project I go en error:

> Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneOS8.4.sdk'

Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934067/swift-does-not-support-the-sdk-iphonesimulator8-4-sdk/32951622#32951622

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to re-install Xcode (which works because it has the same effect), just quit Xcode and go to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/" and remove the "iPhoneOS8.4.sdk" folder from that directory. Be sure to make an external copy if you still need it so you can put it back later. Then restart Xcode, clean, and build. Worked for me. (Assumption: you're building with iOS 9 Base SDK as Mark suggests.)

Answer (score 0):

Set the Base SDK build setting to Latest iOS, and the error should go away.

[image]

If your app needs to support iOS 8, set the deployment target to iOS 8.