# Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

Just updated to Xcode 7.0.1, running on El Capitan (GM) with SIP disabled. And now every time I try to compile a Swift project I get this error;

```
<unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried compiling for actual devices as well and get:

```
<unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneOS8.4.sdk'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

My deployment target was originally set to 8.0, I've tried setting it to 9.0 but that makes no difference. My Base SDK is set to Latest iOS(iOS 9.0).

This is across all my Swift projects, even when I create a new project, I still get this error.

It doesn't seem to be affecting Objective-C. One thought I've had, is could this be an issue with SIP being disabled? It doesn't look like a permissions error but I can see no other reason why this isn't working.

Comment: Which iOS simulator is selected in Xcode for the build?

Comment: I've tried a few, but they're all running iOS9. I'm mainly trying on the iPhone 6S as there's no way that couldn't be iOS9

Comment: Same problem here. I updated to 7.0.1 but still in Yosemite.

Comment: Hmm.. I may file a bug report. There doesn't seem to be anything in my configuration that should be causing this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happened to me when I had simultaneously installed both `Xcode 7` and `6.4` and after automatic update I was left with `7.0.1` only.

One indication that something got messed up was output of `xcodebuild -sdk -version`:

```
xcodebuild[29131:8243992] [MT] DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '<DVTFilePath:0x7fac2ae3c800:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk'>': SDK with name 'iphoneos9.0' being superceded by SDK with 'iphoneos9.0'.
...
iPhoneOS8.4.sdk - iOS 9.0 (iphoneos9.0)
SDKVersion: 9.0
Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk
PlatformVersion: 9.0
PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
ProductBuildVersion: 13A340
ProductCopyright: 1983-2015 Apple Inc.
ProductName: iPhone OS
ProductVersion: 9.0
...
```

There might be easier way to solve this, but reinstalling `Xcode 7.0.1` fixed it for me.

Comment: I had the same configuration before upgrading to 7.1, reinstall fixed it!

Comment: Happend to me with Xcode 7.1 (renamed to keep it) and Xcode 6.4. Appstore updated and both versions were gone. It's kinda scary that the renamed Xcode is automatically deleted. Now I'm forced to reinstall everything. :/

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to re-install Xcode (assumption: you're building for iOS 9), just quit Xcode and go to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/" and remove the "iPhoneOS8.4.sdk" folder from that directory. Be sure to make an external copy if you still need it so you can put it back later. Then restart Xcode, clean, and build. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case the old SDK folders were just symbolic links, not real files, but getting rid of them still fixed the problem.